# How to call specific property of constructor used in dictionary object

Tags: c#

...

```
class Course
{
    private string cid;
    private string cname;

    public string id
    { 
      get => cid;
      set => cid = value;
    }

    public string name
    {
        get => cname;
        set => cname = value;
    }

    public Course(string courseId, string courseName)
    {
        id = courseId;
        name = courseName;        
    }


}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Course course1 = new Course("CTS1851", "Internet Web Foundation");
        Course course2 = new Course("CGS2820", "Web Programming");
        Course course3 = new Course("CGS2821", "Advanced Web Programming");
        Course course4 = new Course("COP2361", "C# Programming");



        Dictionary<string, Course> Courses =
            new Dictionary<string, Course>();

        Courses.Add(course1.id, course1);
        Courses.Add(course2.id, course2);
        Courses.Add(course3.id, course3);
        Courses.Add(course4.id, course4);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Course> kvp in Courses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}",
                kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }





    }
}
```

...

My goal here is to have the console show the course id when i call the key and only the course name when the value is called, but can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this while keeping the "key, value" for the dictionary "string, course". any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please review [mre] guidance on posting code for debugging questions. It is very unclear what exact problem you have with *dictionary*. As part of the example showing what actual and expected outputs are is important. Also it helps to have separate statement for everything - instead of inlining a lot of code into single line till you understand what is going on (mostly for your own benefit) - adding `Course course = kvp.Course;` likely would helped to realize that dictionary related code/text is not related to what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `kvp.Value` with `kvp.Value.name`

Also note, in C# public properties are UpperCamelCase so it should be `Name` not `name`. I'd also recommend looking up record types in C# as they are the standard way of handling these sorts of pure data types.